Refactor the method
I have a method that works with both a list and a single element. Is there a concise way to accept either of these types (perhaps using generics, etc)
  public void write(MyInter elemen){
        write(List.of(element));
    }
  public  <T extends MyInter> void write(List<T> elements) {
  ...
  elemets.forEach(...)
  ...    
  }

I'd like to reduce the code. Varargs don't fit, and I also tried generics, but they're too general. In general, I want everything to be in one method, a method that will accept either an element or a list and work with it, but without unnecessary code. Something like this:
...
if(obj instanceof MyInter) obj.execute()
else elemets.forEach(obj->obj.execute())
...


What's wrong with your last piece of code? I honestly don't see why it has to be in one method. Don't really see the point of this. Also, to know if code is unnecessary or necessary, we need to know why you need that type of method. This can be done in a lot of ways.

How would that be better?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010214/can-we-pass-a-single-object-as-well-as-as-list-of-objects-in-the-same-generic-pl

Can you clarify what actual problem you're trying to solve with this?  Why specifically can't the method which accepts the list simply iterate over that list and invoke the method which accepts the object on each element?  (Or, reversing that, why can't the method which accepts the object not wrap that object in a list and invoke the method which accepts the list?)

the instanceof solution is worse IMHO; similar to the List.of one... I would prefer a write(MyInter) that does write one element and a write(List) that calls the first one ((since varargs is not an option))

@David The method writes to the database, so this list should be processed within a single transaction in the write method

I thought there might be a more optimal solution, but judging by a similar question, there's no such thing in Java. So I'll just leave the method overloading

A List can contain a single element so why do you need a separate method to process a single element?
